# lsof выводит не все файлы

Tags: linux, файлы, файловая-система, процесс

Существует задача - вывести все файлы,открытые процессом с заданным PID. Для этого я пытался использовать `lsof -p <PID>`.Но я столкнулся с проблемой,что lsof выводит не все файлы,которые открывает программа. Допустим,я открыл программу leafpad, внутри этой программы обратился к файлу `/root/Desktop/qwerty.txt` (то есть открыл его).При вызове `lsof -p <PID leafpad>` в списке открытых файлов не выводится `/root/Desktop/qwerty.txt`. Вопрос: почему lsof не выводит этот файл?
Так же имеется вопрос: Откуда lsof собирает информацию об открытых файлах? Насколько я знаю,lsof ищет эту информацию в `proc/<PID>/fd`, но внутри этой директории(в большинстве случаев) находятся только broken link на pipe и socket.

Comment: Сидеть в иксах рутом — очень нездоровская идея, BTW.

Answer (score 3):

> Допустим,я открыл программу leafpad, внутри этой программы обратился к файлу ... почему lsof не выводит этот файл?

Вероятнее всего алгоритм работы leafpad такой: открыть файл→прочитать его в память→закрыть файл. Далее все действия с «файлом» происходят исключительно с его копией в памяти. При сохранении файл заново открывается и записывается на диск.

Таким образом к моменту вызова `lsof` файл (файловый дескриптор) уже фактически закрыт.

> Откуда lsof собирает информацию об открытых файлах? Насколько я знаю,lsof ищет эту информацию в `/proc/<PID>/fd`, но внутри этой директории(в большинстве случаев) находятся только broken link на pipe и socket.

Да, именно оттуда. А также может использоваться информация из `/proc/<PID>/{fdinfo,maps,stat}`, что даёт дополнительную информацию об открытых файловых дескрипторах, информацию о отображённых в память (но, возможно, закрытых) файлах и общие данные по процессу соответственно. То что некоторые «симлинки» выглядят битыми при просмотре — не критично, они дают необходимую информацию, а при открытии (если оно возможно) они будут ссылаться на правильные данные.

Comment: Чем гадать на кофейной гуще, запустить программу под *strace*, всё станет понятно.